# How to solve Twisty Movement from Codeforces?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I've read the editorial but it's very short and claims something I don't understand why it's true. Why is it equivalent to finding longest subsequence of `1*2*1*2*`?. Can someone explain the solution step by step and justify the claims at every step? http://codeforces.com/contest/934/problem/C

Here is the 'solution' from the editorial, but as I said it's very short and I don't understand it. Hope someone can guide me to the solution step by step justifying the claims along the way, not like in the solution here. Thanks.

> Since `1 ≤ ai ≤ 2`, it's equivalent to find a longest subsequence like
>   `1 * 2 * 1 * 2 *` . By an easy dynamic programming we can find it in
>   `O(n)` or `O(n2)` time. You can see `O(n2)` solution in the model
>   solution below. Here we introduce an O(n) approach: Since the
>   subsequence can be split into 4 parts `(11...22...11...22...)` , we
>   can set `dp[i][j](i = 1...n, j = 0..3)` be the longest subsequence of
>   `a[1...i]` with first `j` parts.

Answer (score 1):

I also think that the cited explanation is not super clear. Here is another take.

You can collapse an original array

```
1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 1
```

into a weighted array

```
2 3 2 2 1
^ ^ ^ ^ ^
1 2 1 2 1
```

where numbers at the top represent lengths of contiguous strips of repeated values in the original array.

We can convince ourselves that

1. The optimal flip does not "break up" any contiguous sequences.
2. The optimal flip starts and ends with different values (i.e. starts with 1 and ends with 2, or starts with 2 and ends with 1).

Hence, the weighted array contains enough information to solve the problem. We want to flip a contiguous slice of the weighted array s.t. the sum of weights associated with some contiguous monotonic sequence is maximized.

Specifically, we want to perform the flip in such a way that some contiguous monotonic sequence `112`, `122`, `211` or `221` has maximum weight.

One way to do this with dynamic programming is by creating 4 auxiliary arrays.

1. `A[i]` : maximal weight of any 1 to the right of i.
2. `B[i]` : maximal weight of any 1 to the left of i.
3. `C[i]` : maximal weight of any 2 to the right of i.
4. `D[i]` : maximal weight of any 2 to the left of i.

Let's assume that if any of `A,B,C,D` is accessed out of bounds, the returned value is `0`.

We initialize `x = 0` and do one pass through the array `Arr = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1]` with weights `W = [2, 3, 2, 2, 1]`. At each index `i`, we have 2 cases:

1. `Arr[i:i+2] == 1 2`. In this case we set

   - `x = max(x, W[i] + W[i+1] + C[i+1], W[i] + W[i+1] + B[i-1])`.
2. `Arr[i:i+2] == 2 1`. In this case we set

   - `x = max(x, W[i] + W[i+1] + A[i+1], W[i] + W[i+1] + D[i-1])`.

The resulting `x` is our answer. This is an O(N) solution.